# Is :hover only limited to child elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I just saw this code in an answer:

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <img class="overthumb" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.overthumb { display: none; }

.thumbnail:hover .overthumb {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px; left: 15px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/6wQp3/

For this code to work `.overthumb` must be a child of `.thumbnail`.

But if some one has this code:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
</div>
<p>tttttttttt</p>
```

How would you select the `p` tag if `.thumbnail` is hovered?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/6wQp3/1/)**

You can use the [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

```
.thumbnail:hover + p {
    background:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following selector

```
.thumbnail:hover + p
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6wQp3/2/